# Issues loading Firebase data into web application

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am having problems in my web application regarding loading the data into the application.

The application looks like this: 
[image: App]

The data is saved into the database under the users display name. The code looks like this to save the data:

```js
function saveToFB(bookName) {

  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

  name = user.displayName;

  firebase.database().ref('Book/' + name).push({
    book: bookName,
  });

};
```

So when the user saves the data it is saved under a node which is their display name. I currently have 2 signed up users both with different display names and different data within each. The JSON looks like so:

[image: JSON]

However, when it comes to loading the data into the application I am having some issues. Rather than loading the data corresponding to the currently signed in user, it simply loads the data from the last signed in user.

[image: app2]

As you can see from this screenshot - The console clearly states that Joe is logged in but is being shown George's data.

Not even refreshing the page populates the application with the correct data. I first have to add a new book, which does not get displayed as it is under Joe not George, and only then once I refresh the page does it show Joe's data.

But then the issue occurs again when I sign back out and into another account and the previous data is displayed.

My JS for the rest of the application looks like this:

```js
function refreshUI(list) {
var lis = '';
var lis2 = '';
var lis3 = '';

      for (var i = 0; i < 10 && i < list.length; i++) {
        lis += '<li style="width: 150px" data-key="' + list[i].key + '">' + list[i].book + genLinks(list[i].key, list[i].book) +'</li>';
      };
      for (var i = 10; i < 20 && i < list.length; i++) {
        lis2 += '<li style="width: 150px" data-key="' + list[i].key + '">' + list[i].book + genLinks(list[i].key, list[i].book) +'</li>';
      };
      for (var i = 20; i < 30 && i < list.length; i++) {
        lis3 += '<li style="width: 150px" data-key="' + list[i].key + '">' + list[i].book + genLinks(list[i].key, list[i].book) +'</li>';
      };
        document.getElementById('bookList').innerHTML = lis;
        document.getElementById('bookList2').innerHTML = lis2;
        document.getElementById('bookList3').innerHTML = lis3;
    };

function genLinks(key, bkName) {
var links = '';
links += '<a href="javascript:del(\'' + key + '\',\'' + bkName + '\')"><i id="deleteBook" class="material-icons">delete</i></a> ';
links += '<a href="javascript:remove(\'' + key + '\',\'' + bkName + '\')"><i id="removeBook" class="material-icons">clear</i></a> ';
links += '<a href="javascript:select(\'' + key + '\',\'' + bkName + '\')"><i id="selectBook" class="material-icons">check</i></a>';
return links;
};

function del(key, bkName) {
var deleteBookRef = buildEndPoint(key);
  deleteBookRef.remove();
}

function select(data, book, key) {
document.getElementById('selectBook').style.color="blue";
document.getElementById('selectBook').style.color="blue";

var selectBookRef = book;
  document.getElementById('alltext').value += selectBookRef + ',';
}

function buildEndPoint (key) {
return new Firebase('https://project04-167712.firebaseio.com/Book/' + '/' + name + '/' + key);
}

var bookList = firebase.database().ref('Book/' + name);


// The issue - I think

bookList.on("value", function(snapshot) {
var data = snapshot.val();
var list = [];
    for (var key in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            book = data[key].book ? data[key].book : '';
        if (book.trim().length > 0) {
            list.push({
            book: book,
            key: key
            })
        }
    }
}
refreshUI(list);
});
```

What i'm looking for is for a user to log into their account and see their data and no one else's.

Any help with this issue would be great - This is the only method i've tried so far to only show the user their data and not all the other users' data along with it - So if there are any other suggestions on how to do this i'd appreciate it.

Comment: You can add a field 'createdBy' and filter based on it

Comment: Where is the code showing how you fetch the data?

Comment: bookList.on("value", function(snapshot) {
var data = snapshot.val();
var list = [];
    for (var key in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            book = data[key].book ? data[key].book : '';
        if (book.trim().length > 0) {
            list.push({
            book: book,
            key: key
            })
        }
    }
}
refreshUI(list);
});

Comment: Its the bit at the end of the JS.. and this populates the list items

Comment: Vindhyachal - What do you mean? could you please explain?